# Position fixed throws off background image

Tags: html, css

I need to have some text go over a background image. Looking around it seems like the way to do it is like this:

```
<div align="center" style="">
    <h1>About Us</h1>       
    some text and more for the sub headline
    <br/><br/>

    <img src="aboutbg.jpg" style="width:500px; position:fixed; z-index:-1;" />

    <div style="width:500px;  position: relative; z-index:1;" >
        About Us
    </div>
</div>
```

but something seems to be off with the `position:fixed` of the `<img>`, and it's not centered correctly. The end result is:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

It's obeying the `text-align` statement you have on an ancestor element. You'll need to set its `left` position to 0, and possibly `top` as well.

It would probably be better to make the background an actual background.

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/nature);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 400px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>About Us</h1> some text and more for the sub headline
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div style="width:500px;  position: relative; z-index:1;">About Us</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do left:0; it throws it all the way to the left of the screen which is not what I need. I need it centered under the About Us.

Comment: You'd need to do `left: 50%; margin-left: -300px;` (or whatever half the image width might be).

Comment: The left: 50%; margin-left: -250px; does what I need. I'll dive deeper into it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with inline styles.

```
    <div style="background:url('aboutbg.jpg') no-repeat;width:500px;text-align:center;">
        <h1>About Us</h1>       
        <p>some text and more for the sub headline</p>
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li style="border-right:1px solid #000;display:inline;margin-right:7px;padding-right:7px;"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li style="border-right:1px solid #000;display:inline;margin-right:7px;padding-right:7px;"><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
            <li style="display:inline;"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```